# Scala: Is there any way to override "not equals" (!=)?

Tags: scala, overriding, equals, equals-operator

I'm writing a DSL that generates SQL.  The syntax for loading a table is:

```
    session.activateWhere( _.User.ID == 490 )
```

This will select from the User table where the ID column is 490.  I can use "==" because I can override "equals()" to generate the correct SQL.  My problem is that "!=" doesn't work because it calls equals() and then negates the result.  Sadly "!=" is final so I can't override it.  Is there any way in my equals() method to tell that it was called as part of !=?

I've implemented a "<>" operation that logically does the same thing as "!=" and it works fine:

```
    session.activateWhere( _.User.ID <> 490 )
```

My issue is that not only is "!=" valid syntax (to the compiler) but it will run and generate the exact opposite of what the user intends.

Comment: `<>` is the SQL "not equals" operator anyway.

Comment: Are you trying to fix Slick? ;)
http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html

Answer (score 5):

As you say, `!=` is (similarly to `==`) final and so cannot be overridden - with a very good reason. That is why most DLSs use `===` as an alternative.

The `==` and `!=` operators have a very well defines meaning for all objects in Scala. Changing the meaning for some objects would be, in my opinion, very dangerous.

Comment: Normally I totally agree.  However, in this case I'm attempting to override equals() on a class that is only used to generate the SQL.  The class has a private constructor so it can't be used outside of this context which generally makes it safe.

That said, I understand the overall reasoning for making != final.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `==` and `!=`, you have to override `equals`, `hashcode` and `canEqual` (trait Equals)

It is not a simple as it looks, you have to be carreful.

There is some examples over the net.
For example : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s16.html

Another one : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/Qosfawmaecw/RUWigwvVtQ4J